# Flutter installation not working?

Tags: flutter

I have installed the `flutter` folder in `Program Files (x86)` and have added the `.../flutter/bin` directory to path. Running flutter doctor in the `flutter_console.bat` window or just a normal command prompt window gives nothing
and running as admin in either gives me the error:

```
Updating flutter tool...
\flutter\.pub-cache was unexpected at this time.
```

What do I do? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is probably not the way to go about it but what I did to solve this problem was remove this line

```
SET pub_cache_path=%FLUTTER_ROOT%\.pub-cache
```

from `flutter/bin/flutter.bat`. I then went through the installation process and once everything was working changed the `flutter.bat` file back by adding the line again and then ran `flutter` again. I got no errors from doing this and I appreciate that this is probably not the correct way to go about solving this problem but it worked for me so I am posting it as the answer if others want to try it.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't put Flutter in `Program Files`. These folders are not writeable by non-Admin users so may fail when trying to write files if you're not running your console/editor as Admin.

Answer (score 4):

Cut flutter folder from Program Files (x86) to Program Files. It has problem with x86 but works fun in x64 directory. And update the environment variables with the new path.

Answer (score 1):

I had mine fixed by just removing the special character from the directory name.
I organize my folders with numbering and parenthesis like so

```
1) xyz
2) yza
3) aws
...
25) flutter
```

I changed it to

```
1) xyz
2) yza
3) aws
...
25 flutter
```

don't forget to change it in environment variables too

Answer (score 0):

1.Set the environment variable by copying the bin directory ex: C://programfiles/flutter/flutter/bin

2.Go to Control panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts-> Change environment variables -> Choose User variable -> Path -> Edit -> New -> Paste the link -> click ok

3.Restart Computer -> Open powershell -> Type "Flutter"

4.It should be working now.

Comment: I already added it to path as you would know if you read through my question.

Comment: Also a restart is not required when you change the PATH variable. Just open a new PowerShell window and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1- First make sure that you running cmd or powershell as admin.

2- If didn't work try to restart PC.

3- If didn't work try to move the flutter folder to another path and make sure that you did the required changes on Environment Variables.

4- If didn't work, just delete the cache folder in "flutter\bin" and try again by writing

```
flutter doctor
```

Also as a note, try not to put your flutter directory inside the special directories which need a special permissions like Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally installed it in d:\Program Files (x86) which is NOT the system folder, but an alternate install location that does not require elevated privs, and I was getting this error. I moved flutter to just d:\flutter and it worked. I don't know if it was spaces or the parentheses that was problematic.

Answer (score -1):

Extract the zip file and place the contained flutter in the desired installation location for the Flutter SDK (for example, `C:\src\flutter;` do not install Flutter in a directory like `C:\Program Files\` that requires elevated privileges).

You are now ready to run Flutter commands in the Flutter Console!